# Attachment file is invalid - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sp-send-dbmail

(Sql Server 2014, Windows Server)
Running into a frustrating issue running a Database Mail stored procedure including an attachment on a local shared server.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
...
,@file_attachments = '\\localServer\subfolder\file.txt
```

Unfortunately the error is arising on executing this:

```
Attachment file \\localServer\subfolder\file.txt is invalid.
```

Searching online, it looks as though a common cause of this is that the SQL service account (Or server agent? This was unclear) does not have permission to the file system specified. However, this shouldn't be the case here. The domain account assigned to the SQL service account(s) can view and modify all files that are trying to be attached.

Through SQL configuration manager both the **SQL Server** and **SQL Server Agent** services have been supplied with a domain administrator user account which has access to this server. However the issue is still occuring. These services *have* been restarted.

One further complication is that launching with another attachment from the same server, e.g:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
...
,@file_attachments = '\\localServer\another_subfolder\file.txt
```

Works exactly as expected, and the mail with attached file is sent successfully. The permissions on this folder/file are identical to the permissions on the folder/file which fails on attachment.

What could be causing this, are any further changes to the SQL services required?

Comment: What does "shouldn't be the case here" mean? What account is being used to run SQL Server and SQL Server Agent? Did you log on to the server *as that account* and try to access `\\localServer\subfolder\file.ext`?

Comment: Hiya - yes, to clarify logged in as the account on the server, it does indeed have access to view and modify both paths that are being used in the EXEC sp_send_dbmail.

Comment: shared folders have two levels of permissions: one for the share and one for the directory. Make sure the service account has sufficient permissions for both.

Comment: @lptr Indeed the service account has full permissions for both.

Comment: How about if you move the file that works to the folder that doesn't? If you have really logged on as the service account and verified that account can access the file, then it's likely the error message is more accurate than your Google search. Have you tried opening the file and making sure it isn't corrupt? Have you validated that your SMTP server isn't blocking that extension? Have you tried manually sending an e-mail with that same attachment through the same SMTP server?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you - on testing it seems the problem only occurs when trying to attach an Outlook .msg type extension (Not completely confirmed, but a pattern seems to be emerging). These files can be manually opened / viewed by the account user no problem, and can similarly be sent through the SMTP server manually.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a comment but don't have the reputation :).

I ran into some issues when file names would have invalid characters in them (different encodings/character pages). try to rename the 'file to be sent' to a new simple name and retry sending it, to ensure it's not caused by this. In my case (~~10 years ago), the file name seemed ok when viewing it from windows explorer but the mail client did not accept the name.

Also, you could use mklink to create a local folder pointing to that share. In this way you eliminate the UNC pathing issue from the problem.

Comment: after a night's sleep on it, it would break the problem into pieces: copy the file from some_folder to another_folder where it should work. if it works, just copy/paste the file in the same folder (in this case the new file has new permissions). if that does not work, copy the file locally on the SQL server and see if that solves it... Narrowing it down should help.